# PHP output buffer corrupted getting include contents

Tags: php, output-buffering

Stranger things... hard to make this "question". I have an entire website made in php and JavaScrip. The contents are processed in many ways, accessing mySQL and files. One way is just to include a php that build the html string. To include right in the structure of the website, I did a simple output buffer:

```
ob_start();
include_once($url);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo_cont($output);
```

Where echo_cont simply store the contents to print later, on the right place. But a "simple" page that read some photo files and build an album is coming corrupted. Parts of html missing, strange changes like this:

- class=" button2" when should be class="button2" so the element become
  unformatted
- "http  www.mywebsite.com.br folder" when it suppose to be
  "http//www.mywebsite.com.br/folder"...

Other pages are being included right.

I began to use output buffer in this site this year, I don't know if can be a problem of this kind or might be something else, but is not easy to look for clues, is not easy to run the page outside the site because it depends on several libraries - is kinda complex. It seams to me a text encoded and bad decoded later. What do you think?

EDIT: the echo_cont function:

```
$htmlConteudo = '';
function echo_cont($html){
    global $htmlConteudo;
    $htmlConteudo .= $html;
}
```

Comment: have you done a var dump of $output to check your echo_cont() function is not effecting the output

Comment: Make sure that all files you include use the same encoding, preferably UTF-8. If you mix encodings this can happen. Try to open one of the erroneous source files in an editor and make sure it's saved as UTF-8.

Comment: I know it is difficult to make a question that really shows your problem, but we cannot help you if we don't even have a change to reproduce the problem you seem to have. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve One way to approach this problem is step-wise. First echo (or mail) the bit of code before you store it with `echo_cont()`, is that code still ok? Then do the same when you retrieve it. My point is, it must be going wrong somewhere, just track down where.

Comment: I did edit: echo_cont shown above. I will investigate the encoding issue, and try to replicate the effect. I was hoping somebody will look at the symptoms I described and point the right direction... hoping to much! Sorry for the incomplete question, I will try to improve it, with time.

Comment: I just did an "includer" to test the page without the output buffer feature. The problem remains, so the cause is before output buffer. I tried to change header but php returns error - cannot modify it, headers already sent (by the includer, though). I was wondering if should let this question or delete it, it is not focused on the cause but might help other lost developers...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to answer my own question with the ideas of contributors because the problem is not about the php feature, but the way I was investigating - and can happens with you reading my answer.

The issue is: the image displayed in browser is an interpretation of the data sent, as the information shown in developer window. Is not the original data, it is an attempt to make xml/html document from data. In this case, the original data need to be seen, previously from browser interpretation, and it can be with this simple function:

```
function strTag($xmlstr){
    $str = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $xmlstr);
    $str = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $str);
    return nl2br($str);
}
```

Than, the data is captured:

```
ob_start();
include("www_pc/conteudo_imagens.php");
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
echo(strTag($output));
```

Now it is time to get close to the screen and examine all the details. In my case, there was some tags like this:

```
<div style="float:left;width:80px;height:120px;margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;>
```

You can see the quote missing at the end of style declaration (it happens coding late of the night). So when the browser try to rebuild the xml and make it's own interpretation, confusing the analysis when trying to find the error. I'd test in Safari and Firefox, so it is not browser failure, but browser AI limitation. Got to see the original code, AI only in movies!